# How do I make a FaceTime call in macOS for contacts marked, "Siri Found in Apps"?

Tags: facetime

I'd like to make a FaceTime call. To do this, I:

1. Open FaceTime
2. Type the name of my contact
3. Select the contact from the dropdown under the section, "Siri Found in Apps"

However, when I click either the green "Audio" or "Video" buttons, nothing happens. The buttons are not disabled. The buttons depress but have no effect.

[image: Screen capture]

How do I make a call at this point? Why don't the buttons do anything? If the action is not succeeding because of an error, where is the error reported? No error dialogs appear on the screen.

This only happens for me for contacts marked, "Siri Found in Apps". The others work fine. Both the "Audio" and "Video" buttons make an audio and video call respectively. Once I add the email address (the same email address Siri found) to the contact card manually in the Contacts app, then the green buttons actually make a call.

[image: Dropdown]

---

## System Specifications

[image: System Specifications]

Comment: What if you go into Contacts (not FaceTime), find the contact, and then click the "FaceTime" button. (there should be three or four - message, call, mail, etc.). Can you make the call from there?  Do you have any 3rd party sound/video apps for recording and such?

Comment: I can make the calls from Contacts and Messages once I add the email address to the contact card. I realized the problem only occurs when I have no email address in the contact card but Siri finds it and puts it under, "Siri Found in Apps". Calling those contacts elicits the behavior I describe. I updated the question and the title.

Comment: As long as there's a phone number, you should be able to make an audio call (at least).  Since it working everywhere except through Siri, it sounds like a bug and should be reported at [Apple Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/)

Comment: @Allan, I think you last comment is the answer. I filed a bug report with Apple using the link you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is likely a bug.**

As long as there’s a phone number available, you should be able to make a call.  If this is working everywhere as you indicate except via Siri, then it’s a bug.  The best course of action is to report it to Apple: https://apple.com/feedback

Answer (score 0):

The buttons determine which type of message you wish to use. Clicking on Video should bring up a list of video calls you have made. Then you can double click on that call to repeat it. If you have made no calls the list will be empty. In that case, put a contact name or phone number in the search box. A list item will appear and double click on it to initiate call...

Comment: Are you talking about the large green buttons in my screen capture? Those make calls, right? They don't bring up a list of calls.

Comment: They do on my machine but i'm running HighSierra.  The button tells what type of call you want to make and brings up a list. Also a textbox to put in number or contact name.

Comment: so if i click on the video button, i get a list of all the Video calls i've made. if i want to repeat a call i double click on the prior call. if its a new call, i put phone number in textbox and hit return,  if you don't have a list displayed its probably because you haven't mager any calls using Facetime.